torch.cuda.is_available() returns False even after installing PyTorch with CUDA
I have recently installed PyTorch with CUDA support on my machine, but when I run torch.cuda.is_available(), it returns False. I verified my GPU setup using nvidia-smi, and it seems that my system recognizes the GPU correctly.
Here are the steps I've followed so far:

Installed PyTorch with CUDA support using the command pip install torch torchvision torchaudio.

Confirmed that my GPU is recognized by my system using nvidia-smi.

Verified that the correct CUDA version is installed.


Despite this, running torch.cuda.is_available() still returns False. What could be the reason for this issue, and how can I resolve it?
Additional Information:

Operating System: Windows 11

Python Version: 3.10

PyTorch Version: 2.3.1

CUDA Version: 12.5.82

GPU Model: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4060


What I've Tried:

Reinstalling PyTorch with CUDA support.

Updating GPU drivers.

Rebooting the system.


import torch

print(torch.cuda.is_available())  # Returns False
print(torch.cuda.current_device())  # Raises RuntimeError: No CUDA GPUs are available

I have recently installed PyTorch with CUDA support on my machine, but when I run torch.cuda.is_available(), it returns False.

Please use the commands available here https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/ as the pip command you used is not the same, also the current wheels seem not to support CUDA 12.5.

I solved this problem via DELETING ALL TORCH AND CUDA modules on my PC. Then I used Pytorch with Cuda Website and downloaded 11.8 version.
